# "I want $20 worth of this." Or "I want $20 of this

Tags: word-usage, american-english, spoken-english

If someone has to buy something "worth a particular amount", which will be the more natural way to express this?

> 1. I want $20 **worth of X.**
> 2. I want $20 **of X.**

Which version is more common in AmE, the one with "worth" or the one without "worth"?

Answer (score 1):

**Worth of** definition by [Cambridge Dictionary](http://Dictionary.cambridge.org):

A particular amount of money’s **worth of something** is the amount of money that it costs:

> I need $20 **worth of** gasoline.

Both examples are correct. Although I hear "**worth of**" way more often than just "**of**" in the US, but that may vary depending on which state you live in. I'm going to [go out on a limb](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/out-on-a-limb) here and say that it might be a little bit more "*American-ish*" to say **worth of**.

Comment: And can it be used for "specific" things like a packet of chips. Like you want to buy as many chips(packed) as you can with that particular amount  and not specifying the number of packets. Like: I want $20 worth of chips (i.e. I want as many chips packets as I can buy with $20)

Answer (score -2):

The sentence without "worth" does not even make sense.

This is OK:

> I want $20 worth of X.

---

You may say something similar without "worth":

> I want $20 out of the available $100.

or:

> I want $20 from the $100.